# How to insert data to XML using PHP?

Tags: php, xml

I am new to working with both PHP and XML.

What I have is a XML export that I am passing through PHP to go elsewhere, but if there is a blank in the beginning of the XML, the apps cannot read the entire thing and don't display anything.

It is a Timetable being exported:

```
<W1> <!-- Week 1 of the year -->
 <D1></D1>  <!-- Day 1 of the week -->
 <D2>1-2|C-13SJ-Tutor-SJ-C10||O-3-3GEO-SJ-C10||C-10HS-10SOS-SJ-C6|O-2-1GEO-SJ-C10||O-1-2TOU-SJ-C10|||</D2>  <!-- Day 2 of the week -->
 <D3>1-3|C-13SJ-Tutor-SJ-C10||C-10HS-10SOS-SJ-C6||C-10GN-10SOS-SJ-C10|O-3-3GEO-SJ-C10||O-8-11RRSTY-SJ-C15|||</D3>
 <D4>1-4|C-13SJ-Tutor-SJ-C10|O-2-1GEO-SJ-C10|C-10GN-10SOS-SJ-C10||O-3-3GEO-SJ-C10|O-1-2TOU-SJ-C10||C-10HS-10SOS-SJ-C6|||</D4>
 <D5>1-5|C-13SJ-Tutor-SJ-C10|O-3-3GEO-SJ-C10|O-2-1GEO-SJ-C10||O-1-2TOU-SJ-C10||||||</D5>
</W1>
```

In the API that has been written I am trying to catch the empty `D1`and insert dummy data to get it to work.

Based on what I have seen elsewhere in the project, I have come up with:

```
if(empty($d->field('Timetable'))){
  $out.=XML('D1','0-0|||||||||||');}
```

It obviously isn't working, any suggestions would be great. I've had a look at SimpleXML but not sure if that would work with this solution?

Comment: What API is providing the `field` property? What is `$d`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be pretty easy with SimpleXML...

```
$x = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
if (empty((string) $x->D1)) {
    $x->D1 = '0-0|||||||||||';
}
$newXML = $x->asXML();
```

Demo ~ https://eval.in/886288